# Understanding some terms in K-means clustering

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining, computational-geometry, k-means

I am required to write a program that implements `kmeans` clustering for a given dataset (I roughly understand how kmeans algorithm works). Since I want my program to be generic, I'd like to understand the following terms:

For a given data set that has 100 rows and 10 columns (assuming each column is a feature), how do I identify the following parameters:

1. **dimension**: How do I know the dimension of this dataset?
2. **data point**: Does it mean that every cell `[row][col]` is a data point or the whole row is one data point (vector of points)?

Comment: Every dimension corresponds to a feature, a data point is a row, i.e. a point in that NC-dimensional space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to see your dataset from a computation-geometry point of view, where every element of your dataset is a point in a D dimensional space.

Your dataset looks like this, I guess:

```
row0.col0 row0.col1 ... row0.col9
...
row99.col0 row99.col1 ... row99.col9
```

From a [computational-geometry](/questions/tagged/computational-geometry) view, I would interpret this dataset as 100 points, in 10 dimensions.

---

> Dimension

It's the number of columns, so 10. Every column is a coordinate from the mathematical view! ;)

> Data point

Every *row* is a data point! Every *cell* is a coordinate of this point!

---

For example, check my [minimal example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260820/is-sparks-kmeans-unable-to-handle-bigdata), you will see I create 10000000 points (that's the rows in your case), in 64 dimensions (that's the columns in your case).

Comment: Oh GREAT. Thank you very much. So If I want to pick initial random centroids for 5 clusters, I'd choose randomly 5 rows such that each centroid goes for one cluster. Right?

Comment: @Frank every centroid is a point in the same dimensional space as the points of your dataset. So yes, you can pick 5 points at random from your dataset, and use them as the 5 initial random centroids (so you will pick 5 rows from your dataset). You can easily do this with a random generator from [0, 99], since you have 100 points. For example, I would [select randomly like this in C](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/random-numbers-%E2%88%88min-max/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. Really helpful. I have another question. In fact, I still do not (really) understand why do we call the entire row (point). When talking about points, I think of (x,y) point in the data plane.

Comment: @Frank exactly! You think of `(x, y)` as a *point*! That's in 2D (the plane). ;) So in 2D, for a tiny dataset of 7 points, you would have 7 rows and 2 columns. Makes sense? :)

Comment: It DOES make sense! I just understand now. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

But most languages and file formats (e.g. CSV) use one *row* per record and one *column* per dimension. This *spreadsheet* view is very common.

E.g. in Java, most people would read a `double[100][10]` matrix as 100 records, 10 dimensions each.

Some languages are different. Matlab and Julia are column-major IIRC, so there a shape of (100,10) is 100 dimensions, 10 rows.